# Mongodb Aggregation framework group and sort

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure...

```
{
  "id":"documentID"
  "sessionId":"sometext"
  "msg":"sometext"
  "time":"date"
}
```

- sessionId can exist in many documents

I want to aggregate the documents by `sessionId`, the result for each session should contain the set of messages related to the session sorted by time.

Using the MongoDB aggregation framework how can I achieve that?

I have tried to sort first and then group but the messages in each session wasn't sorted for some reason:

```
{ $sort: { "time": 1 } },
{ "$group" : { 
    "_id" : "$sessionId", 
    "msgs" : { "$addToSet" : "$msg" }
} }
```

any suggestions? your answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: $addToSet isn't sorted, you need to use $push

Comment: Thank you .. and if I want to get with each msg the time also in the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
    {$sort:{"time":1}},
    { $group:
        { _id: "$sessionId",
        messages: { "$push": {message: "$msg", time: "$time"} }
        }
    } 
)
```

This will sort the collection based on time then group by session id.  Each session ID group will have an array of sub-documents which contain the message and time of the message.  By sorting then pushing the messages will be ordered by time in your messages array.